# Loop exit not working

Tags: flowgear

So I have a workflow which is supposed to throw an error after a certain condition is satisfied. (False condition) As you can see in the log directly below, it works: I do a loop exit first for the group 'coms' and an error is thrown. However, Flowgear seems to only read the last executed node and then determine the workflows status from that. Since the loop finishes last and is successful, if you look in the second log, you can see that the workflow has been evaluated as 'successful' although an error was thrown inside.

Any ideas how to make the loop break? Also why does flowgear only consider the last node? There should be an option in the error node to stop all execution.

[image: Activity Log]
[image: Execution Result Log]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterator nodes (`Splitter` and `Loop`) will consume the errors. The only way at this stage to get the workflow to return an error is to cause an error in the `AnyError` or `UnhandledError` part of the workflow. I've created a workflow to demonstrate this here: http://flowgear.me/s/UdpGBbd

Hope this helps.

Comment: That was my suspicion! Thank you so much for taking the time to make that sample workflow. Helped a lot.

Comment: It's a pleasure :)